# javascript dynamically create class instance from a class name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have many block of codes that look like this:

```
    .....
    var headerEl = document.createElement("div");
    headerEl.id = "headerDiv";
    document.body.appendChild(headerEl);
    var headerBlock = new Header(headerEl);

    var footerEl = document.createElement("div");
    footerEl.id = "footerDiv";
    document.body.appendChild(footerEl);
    var footerBlock = new Footer(footerEl);
    .....
```

Now I want to create a function "createBlock" that will do the above code, so I just have to pass in the params like this

```
    .....
    var headerBlock = createBlock("headerDiv", Header);
    var footerBlock = createBlock("footerDiv", Footer);
    .....
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
function createBlock (divName, className){
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div")
    myDiv.id = divName;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
    var block = new className(myDiv);
    return block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the apply invocation pattern or `Function.prototype.call` :

```
function createBlock (divName, className){
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div")
    myDiv.id = divName;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
    var block = className.call(null, myDiv);
    return block;
}
```

This will require both constructor functions, `Header` and `Footer`, to be scope-safe by checking for `this`

```
function Header(arg) {
  if(this instanceof Header) {
    //initialise
    return this;
  }
  else {
    return new Header(arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I can't make edit to Header and Footer class to check for `this`. Without checking for `this`, I always get `undefined` for block.

Comment: Then your function may throw an error because `this` will refer to null. Check this example: http://jsbin.com/OWUhIBo/1/edit

Comment: One more thing, I am using TypeScript so if I can make an edit to the Header, Footer class to check for `this`, TypeScript will throw this error at compile time: `function 'constructor' has inconsistent return points. This inspection reports any instances of JavaScript functions which return a value in some circumstances and return without a value in others. While legal, such code almost certainly represents a programming error`

Comment: A return statement in a constructor function is not required, because a newly created object(`this`) will be returned. You can, however, still return `this` in the `if` statement. `if(this instanceof Header) { //initialise return this;} else { return new Header(arg); }`.  I have edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createBlock (divName, className){
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div")
    myDiv.id = divName;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
    var block = new window[className](myDiv);
    return block;
}

var headerBlock = createBlock("headerDiv", "Header");
var footerBlock = createBlock("footerDiv", "Footer");
```

Note the quotes around `"Header"` and `"Footer"`

Comment: I have tried this and got this error: 
    
TypeError: window[className] is not a constructor

Comment: this should work if the classes are declared in the global scope

Answer (score -1):

See [Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript)

You need to use:

```
var newInstance = Object.create(window[className].prototype);
newInstance.constructor.apply(newinstance, params);
```