# create a new class using a string name in typescript

Tags: class, parsing, typescript

I am writing an XML loader/parser (and new to typescript), I can load the XML fine, however I'm trying to dynamically parse the XML data back into a class/object. The problem is, I would like to create a class using a string variable;
ie
`var classNameString:String = "className";`

`var newClass:any = new class(classNameString)`

from my many searches of the internet it doesn't appear possible, and I'm going to have to hardcode the class names. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds same as [Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15339429/629118).

Comment: that's the one, many thanks!

Answer (score 30):

If you have a specific namespace, for all the class you want to create, you can do this:

```
var newClass: any = new (<any>MyNamespace)[classNameString](parametersIfAny);
```

and if they are in the default namespace you can simply use `window`:

```
var newClass: any = new (<any>window)[classNameString](parametersIfAny);
```

### Update

You now need to have the `<any>` cast with latest TypeScript or you get an `Error TS7017 Build:Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.`

Comment: works great... nice and clean!

Comment: does this work also in nodejs?

Comment: @JaumeMussonsAbad: Try it and let me know. Assuming nodejs still uses standard instance creation it should work (of the namespace is correct).

Comment: My first result says it doesn't work in nodejs: "ReferenceError: window is not defined".

Comment: @isgoed: This was never tested with nodejs so you may have additional namespaces present. Please ask a new question showing your code. Thanks

Comment: Any way to accomplish this if the namespace is going to be part of the string? In my case a class will be passed as an option but it could belong to different namespaces

Comment: @discodowney: Interesting problem. Have you tried passing the lot (e.g. `"namespace.classname"`) as the classname parameter value to the `window` version above and see what happens?