# How to convert a "String" value to "Type" in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I want to create a side menu in ionic 2 application where the page navigation component is placed in a external json file fetched with the help of menuService.getMenu function.

MY JSON structure:

```
"menu":[
        {
          "title":"Grid",
          "component":"GridPage"
        }
      ]
```

My Ts:

```
    this.menuService.getMenu().then((menu) => {
    this.menu = menu;
    });

    openPage(menu) {
      console.log("menu", menu.component);
      nav.setRoot(menu.component);
    }
```

Console log prints the string GridPage. I tried to convert using Type as Type(menu.component). But my result in console is a function with anonymous name. Someone please help me on getting the json string converted to component "Type" for navigation to work.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript

Comment: No. I want GridPage (menu.component) to get loaded when nav.setRoot is called. Since it is type of string, i am getting error.

Comment: I see, you need the type, not an instance.

Answer (score 12):

I guess there is a way to get the type of a class by string but I don't know (I don't use TS). A simple workaround would be to

create a map from string to type

```
classes = {
  'MyClass1': MyClass1,
  'MyClass2': MyClass2,
  'Grid': Grid
}
```

and then just look the types up

```
class['Grid']
```

The disadvantage is that you need to know all supported classes in advance.

Comment: Thank you! Got me out of a bind. This should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Angular 2 in depth, but in a well structured application it is straightforward and feasible to get a Type using a string, *if* you know the fully qualified name of the given Type:

```
let typeName = "GridPage";
let ComponentType = MyApp.Components[typeName];
```

---

If you are getting the following type error:

> Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

... then you will need to type cast the preceding namespace (object). I prefer asserting to `any` in this case, as it's shorter than defining an inline interface for a string-based index signature, and you effectively don't lose any type-safety:

```
let ComponentType = (MyApp.Components as any)[typeName];
```

---

Additionally, this approach also works perfectly with modules:

```
import * as Components from "./components";

let ComponentType = (Components as any)[typeName];
```

Comment: Hi @John White. i am getting "cannot read property 'GridPage' of undefined error" on using var check = (<any>this.app.Components)[typevar]; Kindly help

Comment: @Aish123 It means that `this.app.Components` is undefined. This is usually caused by file ordering issues if you compile into a single output file. If you are compiling into a single output file, try specifying reference paths for the compiler to know the correct file order. The error you are getting is not specific to getting types from strings.

Comment: I am not sure whether the command in supported in angular2 typescript. i am getting syntax error in ts. File order does not matter in my case as i am importing all my files on initializing my app.

Comment: @Aish123 What ts error do you mean? The _"cannot read property ... of undefined"_ is not a Typescript compile error, it's a Javascript runtime error.

Comment: typescript is not able to identify this.app.Components.

Comment: @Aish123 What error message are you getting during compilation?

Comment: i am getting "Unresolved javascript functions" on components. I guess Angular2 is not identifying the function components. Do i have to import any package for it.

Comment: @Aish123 If you want to use a specific component type that was determined from a string, you will need to type cast. How else would the compiler know what type it is?

Comment: Actually the question is to convert string to a "Type". I didnt mean some other datatype here. Kindly check the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/Type-interface.html). I have imported this Type from angular2

Comment: @JoseA This answer is more than a year old, nowadays it's preferred to use `obj as Type` instead (because `<Type>obj` is ambiguous in `.tsx` files). I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohnWeisz: Thanks. What about in the following scenario?: <MyType>(<any>document.getElementById('my-id').getAttribute('custom-attribute'). This is not in respect of Angular, but Web Components.

Comment: @JoseA It would be simply `(document.getElementById('my-id').getAttribute(‌​'custom-attribute') as any) as MyType`, or `document... as any as MyType`.