# String literal argument as compile-time type name

Tags: typescript

Given the following types:

```
declare namespace Word {
    interface Application { }
    interface Document { 
        Save(): void;
    }
}
```

I can write multiple overloads as follows:

```
interface ActiveXObject {
    new(progid: 'Word.Application'): Word.Application;
    new(progid: 'Word.Document'): Word.Document;
}
```

which take various string literals and return the corresponding type. Thus, the following would not compile:

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject('Word.Document');

//compilation error here -- Word.Document doesn't have this method
doc.BadMethod();
```

**Is it possible to write a single overload whose return type is the type referred to by the string literal?**

Something similar to this:

```
interface ActiveXObject {
    new(progid: string): typefrom(progid);
}
```

and the compiler would flag as an unrecognized type the following:

```
var nonexistentType = new ActiveXObject('Word.NonexistentType');
```

Comment: interesting question. Related / possible duplicates : [Dynamically loading a typescript class -
 reflection for Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript) and 
 [How to convert a string value to type in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356988/how-to-convert-a-string-value-to-type-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Pac0 Both questions deal with creating an instance at runtime from a string; I am interested in compile-time. AFAICT, all the answers either cast the results to an explicit type, or just use `any`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't flag your post and was reading these also. I'm afraid there would be no elegant simple answer as you wish. I am no expert, though, so I am not turning my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage Mapping type and lookup type. However, you still need declaration a type for looking up.

[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20namespace%20Word%20%7B%0A%20interface%20Application%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20interface%20Document%20%7B%20%0A%20Save()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%0Atype%20Mapping%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20Application%3A%20Word.Application%2C%0A%20Document%3A%20Word.Document%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20ActiveXObject%20%7B%0A%20new%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Mapping%3E(k%3A%20K)%3A%20Mapping[K]%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20doc%20%3D%20new%20ActiveXObject('Document')%3B%0A%0A%2F%2Fcompilation%20error%20here%20--%20Word.Document%20doesn't%20have%20this%20method%0Adoc.BadMethod()%3B)

```
declare namespace Word {
    interface Application { }
    interface Document { 
        Save(): void;
    }
}
type Mapping = {
    Application: Word.Application,
    Document: Word.Document
}
interface ActiveXObject {
  new<K extends keyof Mapping>(k: K): Mapping[K]
}

var doc = new ActiveXObject('Document');

//compilation error here -- Word.Document doesn't have this method
doc.BadMethod();
```

If you can define namespace Word to export class, you have even nicer trick.

```
declare namespace Word {
    export class Application { }
    export class Document { 
        Save(): void;
    }
}

interface ActiveXObject {
  new<K extends keyof typeof Word>(k: K): (typeof Word)[K]['prototype']
}

var doc = new ActiveXObject('Document');

doc.BadMethod(); // error
doc.Save(); // ok
```

Comment: I was considering this, especially since I saw it used in `lib.d.ts` for the `createElement` signature. I would have to use an interface instead of an alias, because these mappings might be spread across multiple files, and would need merging. (Minor point -- in my specific scenario the namespaces would also have to be included as the keys of the mapping type.)

Comment: Hi @ZevSpitz, I've come up with a trick that even requires  less repetition. Check it out.