# How to get a class from a string in TypeScript/JavaScript in an Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, angular, typescript

In my application, I have something like this:

**user.ts**

```
export class User { ... }
```

and right now, I do this:

**app.component.ts**

```
callAnotherFunction(User);
```

How can I do this if I have the class name as a string, that is `"User"`? If possible, how would I check if the variable really is a usable class?

For example:

```
let test = "User";

if (**test is really a usable class**) {
    console.log("Yay!");
    callAnotherFunction(**something to put here**);
} else {
    console.log("Error!");
}
```

I am not sure if this is even possible, but thanks for your input already.

---

All I have found so far is examples like these:

```
let test = "User";
let user = new window[test]();
```

But `user` would then be an instance of `User`. Additionally, it does not seem to work in my Angular 2 application - probably a scope error. If I wanted to try this, what would I need to use instead of `window`?

Comment: You can't. Where would you get a reference to this class if it's not on `window`? Moreover, minified `User` class won't be named so, more likely something closer to `a`. Please, explain what you need this for. The thing you're trying to do looks like a bad idea, and most likely you have XY problem.

Comment: I would like to put dynamic content into an instance of a JavaScript object, for example `{ "class": "User", "name": "estus" }` should result the same like `let user = new User(); user.name = "estus";`. To keep this completely dynamic, I need to get an instance of `User` somehow by the string `"User"`.

Comment: You need to define all classes you need to access this way with `{ provide: 'User', useClass: User }`, inject them with `@Inject('User') user: User`, get them dynamically with injector with `injector.get('User')`. This is cumbersome but it will work. Again, this doesn't explain why you need to do this the hard way. There may be DI patterns that are more idiomatic to the framework, because this one is obviously not one of them.

Comment: I agree, I should find a better way to do what I would like to do. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a reflection question in typescript.

Possibly you could check this out if you haven't

[Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript/15339429#15339429)

Comment: Yes I have already read this, thank you. The examples work for me, but I would like to get the class instead of the instance. In my example above, for `window["String"]` it works as expected. But as my custom class `User` is not in `window`, I cannot access it. How could I access it so i can do `window["User"]` or something similar?

Comment: did you also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38127705/1804189 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35787628/1804189

They explain how it can be done in Typescript 1.8+

Comment: Yes, my main problem now seems to be to find out the namespace that `User` lives in. I followed the usual Angular 2 patterns and there you don't explicitely define namespaces.

Comment: @andreas - were you able to get typescript type from the string using the usual Angular 2 patterns? please provide the any helpful link, I wasn't able to with links provided by Nico