# Angular 5 - instantiate a component from its name as a string

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular5, umd

I know how to init components using `ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AComponentType)`

but the method expects a `Type`, while in my code I have the name of the type as a `string`.

In the Angular API is there a method to resolve by `string`?
If not, how can I convert a string to a `Type` in TypeScript?

In case that none of the above is possible I will resort to a map but it's not so straightforward as the components I need to instantiate will come from remotely fetched UMD angular component library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a class from a string in TypeScript/JavaScript in an Angular 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863007/how-to-get-a-class-from-a-string-in-typescript-javascript-in-an-angular-2-applic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528592/ng2-dynamically-creating-a-component-based-on-a-template

Comment: You should take a look to this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
const classesMap = {
  AComponentType: AComponentType,
  BComponentType: BComponentType
}
```

And then:

```
CreateDynamicComponent(typeName: string) {
    ...
    const componentFactory = ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(classesMap[typeName].prototype.constructor)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, where i need to use a string to select what component to build. After some digging I created a list of the components that is added to the `NgModule`export and entryComponents lists.

> template-components.ts
>
> ```
> export const TEMPLATE_COMPONENTS: Type<any>[] = [
>     Temp1Component,
>     Temp2Component
>   ]
> ```

in my `NgModule` class I just add TEMPLATE_COMPONENTS to both `exports` and `entryComponents`

In the component with the `ComponentFactoryResolver` you generate a list of Types, with the same string as a key.

```
let templateTypes: { [name: string]: Type<{}> } = 
    TEMPLATE_COMPONENTS.reduce((p, c) => { p[c.name] = c; return p }, {})

// templateTypes = {'Temp1Component':Temp1Component,...}

this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(templateTypes[string]);
```

This means that you only have to add the components to one place, simplifying adding more components.

Its probably possible to skip the whole `TEMPLATE_COMPONENTS`in a separate list step and get the list directly from the `NgModule`class, but that will be sometime in the future.