# Dynamically instantiate objects by name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have to parse through unstructured logfiles. These logfiles have multiple different messages. Every message has a specific structure though. For example:

```
TIMESTAMP:MESSAGE_NAME1:PARAM1:PARAM2:PARAM3
TIMESTAMP:MESSAGE_NAME2:PARAM1:PARAM2:PARAM3:PARAM4:PARAM5
```

As you can see these messages are structured but can have different params and different amounts of params. I have over 90 different messages where some of them even have params which can occur multiple times and therefore would be arrays.

What I want to achieve is having a class for every message there is. For that I can already extract the message name. However I don't know how I would instantiate the objects depending on the message name without using a very looong switch statement, which just seems like poor coding to me.

So what I want to be able to do is for example something like this:

```
getInstanceByClassName(className: string, params: any[]) {
    //magic code
    return instance;
}
```

I tried to create a function like that by doing something like it is shown in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339429/11411437

However I get errors, that I cannot instantiate without a `new` keyword.
I am using Typescript.

Edit:

What I have is classes like this:

```
export class Message1 {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
    param3: string;
    param4: string;
    param5: string;
    param6: string;
}
```

I parse the logs and get the message name, for example:

```
let name: string = splitArray[0];
```

Now I want to instantiate the class which I currently would do like this:

```
if (name === "Message1") {
    let message: Message1 = new Message1(splitArray[1], splitArray[2], ...);
} else if (name === "Message2") ...
```

(Or with switch cases..)

Obviously this would result in a lot of if statemens or switch cases.

Is there another way to do this? Especially given that every constructor can have a different number of params.

If you need more information please tell me so I can provide it.

Comment: You should show exactly what you tried in your question. We typically do no write magic code for you, we help you fix what you have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's also unclear how you expect make this type safe since you're passing in a string name which I'm guessing is the constructor's name

Comment: @JuanMendes I added some of my code. I don't expect your magic code. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this and how it could be done. I will of course try to implement it myself. But I would need the concept to do so.

Comment: Whats the point of a `class` of objects if every object _is_ its own class? In javascript you might as well make it just Objects in that case (and typescript probably `Any`)

Comment: easy way is to bind name to your constructor in a ```map```: ```{name1: Message1, name2: Message2}```, then instantiate your message via spread operator: ```new map[name](...splitArray)``` (here you'd have to remove beforehand first elem of ```splitArray``` obviously

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like a single class could be used

```
class Message {
   public messageName: string;
   public time: string;
   public params: string[];
   constructor(logMessage: string) {
       const parts = logMessage.split(":");
       // TODO: Make it a date
       this.time = parts.shift();
       this.messageName = parts.shift();
       this.params = parts;
   }
}
```

If you actually have separate `Message1/2/3/4` classes, that's a different case so you would need some map between strings and the constructors to be able to instantiate them properly.

We would need to see what those classes look like since you'd need to get into generics to keep type safety and from your sample code, these classes look almost copy pasted

Comment: You might be right that a single class could be used. I will check this. The only thing with the params is, that they will have different names that I probably will have to map to a database table. So I thought it might be easier to have named params for each message (class). But maybe I can just loop through the params since they should always have the same sequence for each message.

Comment: If the parameters need completely separate work to be constructed, I don't see how you'd have a generic function to construct unrelated classes. If you do have an example of your actual code, I can probably suggest something more type safe, but it's hard to tell without an actual example.