# How to add generic component in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-dynamic-components

in my angular application i am dealing with a lot of component that dynamically rendered in run time, but i must specify the component before compiling to inject it in the run time, is there is away to load component by it's name as string ... 
say ... i have two component `FirstComponent` And  `SecondComponent` can i store the name of them in an array and them by user action decide which component to be rendered, and it don't want to use if condition on the name or something like this. i want something run generic with it's own in case i change the array or add new component to the array i don't want to change the code wrote.
Thanks A Lot In Advance...
And i am using `ng-dynamic-component` for adding dynamic component to the page,
if there is a way does this library implement it.

Comment: Can you share a code sample you are working on (StackBlitz)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ViewContainerRef**.

It is well explained int his tutorial.

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

```
    classNames.forEach(type=> {
           const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
           const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
             });
```

- **vcRef** refers to object of ViewContainerRef.
- **resolver** refers to
  ComponentFactoryResolver

Comment: the resolver can't accept name as string it says `Argument of type '"TestComponent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<unknown>'.`

Comment: @HassanAhmed I think you can create type from string using this method and then pass to resolveComponentFactory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript