# How to fix ERROR TypeError: Class constructor DyanamicClasses cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: typescript, angular11

this code worked in angular 7. But after upgrading to angular 11 it created error

```
static getInstance<T>(DyanamicClasses, name: string, ...args: any[]) : T {
    const instance = Object.create(DyanamicClasses[name].prototype);
    instance.constructor.apply(instance, args);
    return <T> instance;
}
```

**Class**

```
export namespace DyanamicClasses{
  export class HallmarkMxFieldEditStatusAccessor implements IFieldEditStatus{
    item: any;
    fieldDefinition: FieldDefinition;
    constructor(public _item: any, public _fieldDefinition: FieldDefinition){
      this.item = _item;
      this.fieldDefinition = _fieldDefinition;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38127705/14241253 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35787628/14241253 helped me to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

```
static getInstance<T>(DyanamicClasses, name: string, ...args: any[]) : T {
    const instance = Object.create(DyanamicClasses[name].prototype);
    instance.constructor.apply(instance, args);
    return <T> instance;
}
```

**To**

````
```static getInstance<T>(namspacesName, name: string, ...args: any[]) : T {
    return new (DyanamicClasses)[name](...args);
}
````

And this is working now.