# Is it possible to use a string value to refer to a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

For instance, I have a series of interfaces that describe the entities in my system:

```
interface Company {
  name: string
}

interface Employee {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

And I'd like a generic function to fetch these entities, where an interface name can be passed as a string value.

```
const company = findOne('Company', 1)
const employee = findOne('Employee', 2)
```

Is it possible to add a dynamic return type to the `findOne` function, so that in the example above, `company` and `employee` are known by the compiler as instances of `Company` and `Employee`?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you can create an interface map type and infer your first argument:

```js
interface Company {
  name: string
}

interface Employee {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

type InterfaceMap = {
  Company: Company,
  Employee: Employee,
}

function findOne<Name extends keyof InterfaceMap>(name: Name, num: number): InterfaceMap[Name] {
  return null as any
}

const company = findOne('Company', 1) //  Company
const employee = findOne('Employee', 2) //  Employee
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOICeyA3gFDLIhyYQBcyAzmFKAOYkC%20JJoksiKAURwAbdPggpS5GMCiMAclVoMmrMsmFwFSuo2Yg2nEmHzYUASXDR4SALJxsyALzF1GHHnx13uAgBp1IWxRcWUgkIkAoxgAVxAEMGB0EGQZEAATAHkQCAAeRWpkCAAPSAz6ZABrCHx0GGRLXhsIe2wAPgAKSmo6Aog-ChjMOhAhgCNoAEo6Rut%20VoBtPoBdV3IoCDAYqBTR4WFkLUOCDi4EZMZkc48CZ1TQLJyOgHIfT2eBgEZJ5AB6X-IbxO5xAlwgIjEEjuaUeEBe4UhEA%20yAATD9-uQEaEgA)